# Excluding users from the top command

Tags: top

I'm trying to use the top command and exclude two users from showing in the iteration I'm sending to the textfile.

I have used the `-u='!user'` command-line option, but I can only exclude 1 user with it and am not able to use the option more than once.

I found a suggestion to use the command:

```
o!USER=user <enter> o!USER=user
```

but I'm fairly lost in how to implement it without getting an error.

Comment: Are you using `top` on Linux or on BSD or some other type of UNIX system? Implementations of `top` vary quite significantly, and they have different capabilities for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, would this help?

```
top | grep -ve "user1" -e "user2"
```

Answer (score 6):

It works if you add one filter after another.

Run `top` and add a filter for the first user.  Press <kbd>o</kbd> and enter

```
!USER=user1
```

, then press <kbd>o</kbd> and add the next filter

```
!USER=user2
```

and so forth...

Answer (score 2):

If it were only one user, you could do

```
top -U '!user1'
```

The -U filters by real user id, whereas -u filters by effective user id.

I could not get multiple users to be filtered with this method.